# Don't want to refresh the parent page in web-page when redirect from child page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React and I have website of parent page (A) to child page (B). When I click the button in page A, it is redirect to page B.

If I click the back button from B to A, the page A is refreshed.  However I don't want to refresh the page A. Is there any way to accomplish it?

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far, ideally with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: Do you use `react-router-dom` to route your app?